# how to run one task before initialising the whole project?

Tags: java, gradle, eclipse-plugin, build.gradle

[image]

Hello! I have such subproject inside my whole project. I connected them in setting file in the root of project. I want to make jar file by the shadowJar task (in .languageserver) on initialisation stage of whole project and put this jar file in *.provider. I read about init.gradle, but code that I wrote isn't working.

\> init.gradle

```
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    allprojects { project ->
        println project.name
        if (project.name == 'org.eclipse.buildship.gradleprop.provider') {
            println 'IN PROVIDER'
            def languageServerProject = project(':org.eclipse.buildship.gradleprop.languageserver')
            def shadowJarTask = languageServerProject.tasks.named('shadowJar')
            def shadowJarOutput = shadowJarTask.flatMap { it.outputs.files }.getSingleFile()
            def destinationDir = project.file('libs')
            
            copy {
                from shadowJarOutput
                into destinationDir
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do this task? Maybe are there other ways of implementation my current task? Thank you before for help

Above I wrote what I tried.

Comment: Could you please describe why you want to do it this way? What are you ultimately trying to achieve?